# Anchor the bottom of my tableview to the top of my container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was searching about how can I anchor the bottom of my tableview to the top of my container view, which is in the bottom of my view, so when I press the textfield, the container view shows up, which has a textfield and a button. But how can I see the bottom of my tableview while I'm writing a message in the container view? Something like scroll automatically to the bottom of the tableview when the container with the textfield and the button shows up, so I can see the last cells.

Here is the code of the container view:

```
lazy var inputTextField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Enter message..."
    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.delegate = self

    textField.frame.size.width = 150.0
    return textField
}()


lazy var sendButton: UIButton = {
    let boton = UIButton(type: .System)
    boton.setTitle("Delete", forState: .Normal)
    boton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    boton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSend), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return boton

}()

 // MARK: container

lazy var inputContainerView: UIView = {

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    containerView.addSubview(self.inputTextField)
    containerView.addSubview(self.sendButton)

   //I added some constrains to the textfield and the button

    return containerView
```

Also I have this methods:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return inputContainerView
    }
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: What about declaring the height, top or bottom constraints of the tableview and then modifying the constant of it when you press the textfield.

Comment: How would you do that??

Comment: @EdwJohn you can declare a constraint by dragging it from the storyboard to the class like an IBOutlet and then just changing its constant like this nameConstraint.constant = 10 or the size you want

Comment: Yeah, i tried but it doesn't work. I tried with the bottom and the height and then when i press the textfield the tableview still in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableView's `contentInset.bottom` property to the given height of the container view, then:

```
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height-tableView.frame.height+tableView.contentInset.bottom), animated: true)
```

...to force it to scroll to the bottom.